# Rails 4 scope with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I want to show active users within 1 day.

The Member model and scope:

```
time_range = (Time.now - 1.day)..Time.now
scope :active, -> { where(created_at: time_range, gold_member: true, registered: true) }
```

However, when I call

```
@member = User.active
```

The below error rendered:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x07fe068>
```

Please advise.

The backtrace:

```
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in scope'
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:292:in `scoping'
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:151:in `block in scope'
  from (irb):48
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
  from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
```

Comment: What's this error backtrace?

Comment: And what's your console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't fix your error, but there's a problem with the way you define your scope. Before you do it, you define local variable `time_range`. But the problem is, you define it in the body of your `ActiveRecord` class, so it will be evaluated only one time in production environment, when the class is loaded. You should evaluate your time range inside of lambda:

```
scope :active, -> {
  where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.day)..Time.now, gold_member: true, registered: true)
}
```